# Rails 3: Auto-populating a table upon new user creation with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise to handle my users and as part of my application each user has their own 'todo' list. I'm trying to create 5 items in a new list every time a new user is created (so they have some sample data).

What is the best way to do this? I've looked at migrations and seed.rb but these don't seem to meet my needs.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `:after_create` hook.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :populate_todo

  private
  def populate_todo
    # do your stuff here
  end
end
```